# compare two object having 30-35 field one we getting from DB and other we getting from edited form

Tags: java, playframework

i m having an input form with around 30 to 35 input field where some information are previously filled by user and submit it but some fields are blank .when user edit that form then how can check that (param)object value is changed or not

so if form (param)object value is not changed then discard that object else process to .save()

Comment: Perhaps create two ArrayLists, one each for the the DB version and form version of the values and do a comparison between the two. I'm actually doing something similar but in Play! Scala.

Comment: Also, why do you have up to 30 inputs in a form? That's a UX nightmare.

Comment: i m also working on play framework but requirement is that ,in a single form consist those input fields which are mapping of one to many relationship as a example
in a user detail form i have GEO (geographical ),COUNTRY ,STATE,CITY,SECTOR and LOCALITY all r MODEL and these mentioned in one to many relation so above mention input field + user personal detail input fields in one form.
so if user want to edit that form later and during submit if user does't update any thing then i have to check is there is any change in object which comes from DB and other (param)Object to run save() on it or not